# Can't seem to figure out what's missing before it deletes

Tags: php

I am trying to use my delete button which is connected to a separate file that does the deletion of data in my table on the database.

I have been successful enough to place a button by each row in the data whilst they're displayed but I cannot get it to delete the row as I get this error message:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I believe it's something very small maybe? But I just can't figure out what.

admin.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$pass = "root";
$dbname = "tutor_database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Role</th><th>Email</th><th>Username</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["FirstName"]."</td><td>".$row["LastName"].
        "</td><td>".$row["Role"]."</td><td>".$row["Email"]."</td><td>".$row["Username"]."</td></tr>";
?>
        <td>
       <form method="get" action="delete.php">
           <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
           <input class="btn-default" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
       </form>
     </td>
<?php
}
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$database = 'tutor_database';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//obtain the rowid from $_GET
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = ($_GET['rowid']);
}

  //sql to delete record.
  $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ". $id;

  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "Record deleted!";
  require 'adminPage.php';

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;



?>
```

Would appreciate some new pair of eyes on this.

Thank you.

Comment: sidenote: can you tell us why you're using mysqli_ in one code then going to PDO in the other?

Comment: how is this being populate? `$_GET['id']` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I have tried the PDO approach to displaying data, but couldn't figure out how to place a button next to it that would delete each record displayed. So I took this way as I felt it was easier on me to understand - Still new to this.

Comment: then this is failing you `if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = ($_GET['rowid']);
}` and you may have meant to use `if(isset($_GET['rowid'])){
  $id = ($_GET['rowid']);
}` - Error reporting would have thrown you something about it. seems like `WHERE id = ". $id;` <<< is empty.

Comment: I have tried to use error reporting by placing `error_reporting(-1);` but I'm still getting the SQL error message as I've mentioned before. I'm not sure if I am placing this wrong or if I am meant to add additional code to get it to show me the error.

Comment: well somebody posted an answer for something I already posted above here and 5 minutes prior to it. didn't you try what I told you to use?

Comment: Sorry I have only just seen the message and just trying this out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, was already writing the answer when you added that comment - but added a little more in on top of the failing if block as user was executing the query regardless of the validation result

Comment: well some have a tendancy to take comments and make it their own answer for their personal gain. If what I said didn't work, then something else is breaking your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//obtain the rowid from $_GET
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = ($_GET['rowid']);
}

//sql to delete record.
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ". $id;

$conn->exec($sql);
echo "Record deleted!";
require 'adminPage.php';

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Should be

```
//obtain the rowid from $_GET
if(isset($_GET['rowid'])){
$id = ($_GET['rowid']);

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //sql to delete record.
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ". $id;

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Record deleted!";
    require 'adminPage.php';

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "error: no row id specified";
}
$conn = null;
```

First, your validation is inside a try/catch, which will attempt to execute even when no ID is specified; It's a logic failure, basically. Check the value and determine if one is present before running the query, as it stands you're checking the value then attempting a query anyway whether or not a value is present. Second, you're using `if (isset($_GET['id']))` instead of `if (isset($_GET['rowid']))`

Comment: Thank you, for explaining this to me. I will be sure to try this out.

Comment: Basically, your code will run the SQL query whether or not `$_GET['rowid'] ` exists which will throw a SQL error any time it's ran; Instead, surround the SQL query with the validating if block so that it doesn't run when `$_GET['rowid']` isn't present and won't throw a SQL error - instead it will tell you that `$_GET['rowid']` isn't present

Comment: Thank you for your explaination and help, it worked successfully. :)